# Class 'App\Providers\URL' not found when upload to read server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just upgrade from Laravel4.2 to Laravel5.3 and it work as well in Localhost but when upload to server I got this below errors.

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
1/1
FatalThrowableError in AppServiceProvider.php line 18:
Class 'App\Providers\URL' not found

in AppServiceProvider.php line 18
at AppServiceProvider->boot()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AppServiceProvider), 'boot'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(AppServiceProvider), 'boot')) in /var/www/backoffice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php line 769
at Application->bootProvider(object(AppServiceProvider)) in /var/www/backoffice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php line 752
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(AppServiceProvider), '15')
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(NotificationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(HtmlServiceProvider), object(ExcelServiceProvider), object(DatatablesServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 753
at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 253
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 144
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: Can You please provide us Your `AppServiceProvider` file? But it looks like You don't import `URL` class.

Comment: where i can import it?

Comment: Do you have that `URL` class?  Is it a custom class you created? You might need to import it as @GiedriusKiršys said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this namespace to your AppServiceProvider.php (/app/providers)

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
```

Why you use this ('App\Providers\URL') namespace ? Remove it if not necessary

Comment: is it posible to use

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

Comment: Yes you can use it

Answer (score 10):

I know this issue has been resolved for a while and as I wasn't able to resolve using the proposed answer, I would like to post how it worked for me just in case others face the same issue.

```php
# app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

I hope this may become helpful to somebody in the future.

Comment: I required this for enforcing HTTPs in my Laravel app and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when forcing my laravel app to https
I also used TrustedProxies which is now natively in laravel

```
<?php

  namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

  class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
      /**
       * Bootstrap any application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function boot()
      {
          // force HTTPS
          URL::forceSchema('https');
      }

      /**
       * Register any application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function register()
      {
          //
      }
  }
```